# Search page, using <img alt> to display divs in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, image, search, alt

I am trying to build a jQuery live search that displays the div based on the images `alt` content in HTML.

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634479/jquery-search-and-display-images-based-on-class) that does it using the text from a tag's `class`. I applied it to my Bootstrap example. How can I do this to find it using text in the `alt`? What did I do wrong?

```js
// then, on entering text...
$("#filter").on("keyup", function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    // hide everything,
    $(".media").hide();
    // get the text in the input
    var mySearch = $(this).val();
    var alt = $(this).find("img").attr("[alt*='" + mySearch + "' i]");
    // show any class that contains the input
    alt.show();
  } else {
    $(".media").show();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h2>My Items</h2>

<br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" placeholder=" Search item" />

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Mountain brown bear">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">1</h3>bear hug
  </div>
</div>

<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Russian Road salmon bear">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">2</h3>bear fight
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Uganda contest forest ">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">3</h3>bear stare
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="https://placekitten.com/60/60" alt="UK London Restaurant meat">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">4</h3>bears bath
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Somalia splash Sea">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">5</h3>bear splash
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMvdGe)

Comment: For future reference, all code relevant to your question should be *in* the question, not linked to off-site. I've edited the question for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh yes, sorry. Thanks for pointing that out. And for editing.

Comment: No problem - I've added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in your logic. Firstly you're doing `find('img')` from the reference to the `input`, hence that will never find anything. Secondly, you're searching for a match on the entire `alt` value. Presumably from the description you want to match on each word. You can achieve that by using `filter()` along with a regular expression, something like this:

```js
$("#filter").on('input', function() {
  var mySearch = $(this).val();
  var $media = $(".media");  
  
  if (mySearch.trim().length > 0) {
    var $mediaToShow = $media.hide().filter(function() {
      var re = new RegExp(mySearch, 'gi');
      return re.test($(this).find('img[alt]').prop('alt'));
    });
    $mediaToShow.show();
  } else {
    $media.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h2>My Items</h2><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" placeholder=" Search item" /><br/><br/>

<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Mountain brown bear">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">1</h3>bear hug
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Russian Road salmon bear">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">2</h3>bear fight
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Uganda contest forest ">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">3</h3>bear stare
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="UK London Restaurant meat">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">4</h3>bears bath
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Somalia splash Sea">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">5</h3>bear splash
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note the use of the `input` event over `keyup`, as the former will also work when content is pasted in to the field.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Rory. A query though - `var result = re.test($(this).find('img[alt]').prop('alt'));` Can you explain this part? why does is look for the property `alt` in `img[alt]`? why not just `img`?

Comment: Glad to help. That's looking for any `img` elements which have an `alt` attribute for a slight performance benefit. You could just use `img` by itself, but that would select all images, even those without an `alt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it without libraries, but you need to polyfill includes for IE support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill

```js
document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.media').forEach(function (element) {
    element.style.display = element.querySelector('img').alt.includes(event.target.value)
    ? 'block' 
    : 'none'
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h2>My Items</h2>

<br />
<input class="form-control" type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" placeholder=" Search item" />
<br/>
<br/>

<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Mountain brown bear">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">1</h3>bear hug
  </div>
</div>

<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Russian Road salmon bear">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">2</h3>bear fight
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Uganda contest forest ">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">3</h3>bear stare
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="https://placekitten.com/60/60" alt="UK London Restaurant meat">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">4</h3>bears bath
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.placebear.com/60/60" alt="Somalia splash Sea">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">5</h3>bear splash
  </div>
</div>
```